# How many ways are there to do this experiment?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I don't want the full solution rather a step in the right direction. I believe what I have so far is right but I just would like to verify and know the final basic steps to find out how many ways the experiment can be performed. Here's the question:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it from the beer's perspective.  Going down the line, what can happen to each beer?

Comment: Correction: so would the final answer be C(n+10, 10)? As there are n>=10 students to choose 10 students from and 10 different types of beer which each student can only drink 1 type of?

Comment: I think it would be permutations instead of combinations.  P(n,10).  Another way to think of it is to imagine each beer has a labeled chair in front of it.  How many ways can you fill the seats?  The first bullet about picking the group of 10 is unnecessary.  Just go from the pool (n) to the seats (10).